# Render clothing only (no base figure) while not showing hidden/rear parts

Tags: mask, render-settings

This is my first time posting on this forum, so please be gentle :) I'm not an expert in these areas so apologies if my questions are ignorant, or if people have solved these problems a million times before and my googling just isn't good enough.

I am currently an indie developer who is making a 2D game which includes an inventory/paper doll system. I have been using DAZ Studio for many years (currently using v4.20) and the thought occurred to me that I could use the stuff I've bought to render clothing/armour which I could then overlay on top of a base figure, since in my game everything is a 2D layer.

So far, so good. But the issue is how to “cut out” the parts of the clothing that would sit behind the base figure, for example the back of a helmet.

These are the options I've thought of:

1. Fit the clothing to the base figure. Hide the base figure. Render the clothing. Use PhotoShop to manually erase the parts that wouldn't be visible.

   I don't like this idea because it would be incredibly manually intensive – I'd have to work on each item of clothing or outfit individually, and if I don't do it perfectly it will look terrible. However, it does have the advantage that if the base figure isn't rendered, transparency effects will work correctly (see 2 and 3 below).
2. Colour the base figure bright green. Fit the clothing to the base figure. Render the clothing on top of the base figure. Use PhotoShop to select by green colour and hit delete. (Basically similar to a green screen in a movie studio).

   Slightly less manually intensive than 1, but is prone to leaving some artefacts around the edges. Also, for semi-transparent layers or things like lace, the green background shows through and tints the base figure green.
3. Colour the base figure white. Fit the clothing to the base figure. Render the clothing on top of the base figure. Use PhotoShop to select by white colour and hit delete.

   Somewhat solves the problem of the greenish tinge on the base figure, but lightens the colour of base figures with dark skin at those areas. It is also prone to some edge artefacts like 2. Also, I would need to manually deselect any white items of clothing accidentally selected, which increases the manual effort slightly more than 2.

Ignoring anything to do with shadows for now, is there another, better option than the above that I haven't thought of? Is there some magical way to have a “transparent” base figure that also blocks out anything behind it?

Any ideas would be welcome here because none of my 3 options above are great. In case it matters, I'm using the iray render engine.

Thank you.

Comment: You may find a way to render the 3D model with 2...4 times higher pixel dimensions than you finally need. That makes possible to expand by one pixel the area you delete with the color based selection and remove in this way the half-colored transition zone without making a gap when the image is shown in the final lower resolution. Advanced deletion by selection based on key color can also clean off the color contamination. It's in new Photoshop, but not in legacy stuff. I would try GIMP's color to alpha. BTW screenshots would make the actual problem more clear. My comment was based on guessing.

Comment: Please tag the question with the software you are using.

Comment: @Scott the 3D modelling software is DAZ Studio, but the 2D application can be any imaging software. I personally use PhotoShop - should I add this to the tags?